# Create Trial Balance via Sql in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am new to Sql, and need some guidance to create a Trial Balance via Sql query in MySql.
Consider the following scenario:

Two Tables:

- `Accounts`
- `Transactions`

**`Accounts` Table fields details:**

- AccNo (PK)(`varchar`) (5)
- AccName (`varchar`)(50)
- AccOpBal (`double`)

**`Transactions` Table fields details:**

- TransID (`int`) (Auto Increment) (PK)
- AccNo (`varchar`) (5)
- TransDt (`DateTime`)
- TransDebit (`Double`)
- TransCredit (`Double`)

Now I need a SQL query based on `transDt` date range(for e.g 01st Jan-14 to 31sth Jan-2014) which will return:

`AccNo`

`AccOpBal`

`TransDebit`  (Sum of monthly transaction i.e Jan-2014)

`TransCredit`  (Sum of monthly transaction i.e Jan-2014)

`TransDebit`  (Sum of **Yearly** transaction i.e from 01st July-2013 to 31st Jan 2014 or YTD)

`TransCredit`  (Sum of **Yearly** transaction i.e from 01st July-2013 to 31st Jan 2014 or YTD)

It is not necessary that every `AccNo` has opening balance (`AccOpBal`), likewise, it is also not necessary that every `AccNo` has transactions (`TransDebit` or `TransCredit`). But if an `AccNo` has any, it should be in query.

**UPDATE Picture of sample trial added**
[image: SampleTrialBalance]

Comment: @rene I haven't...because I have only basic knowledge about sql..Like SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE...

Comment: @rene thanks...I will definitely read knowledge base you've provided, meanwhile I am waiting for some sample code...I am a quick learner so any starting code will help..

Comment: you should provide the format of the report you want. If you want double sided report having credits in one side and debits in one side. Or in one single tabular form with debit and credit side by side?

Comment: @krishnasahoo I've added sample picture for Trial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that result with a select over a union of two queries, one for the month to date and one for the year to date figures.

```
select accno, accopbal, sum(mtd_d), sum(mtd_c), sum(ytd_d),sum(ytd_c)
from 
(   select ao.accno
         , ao.accOpBal
         , 0 as mtd_d
         , 0 as mtd_c
         , 0 as ytd_d
         , 0 as ytd_c
    from accounts ao
    left outer join transactions tn on tn.accno = ao.accno
    where tn.accno is null
    union
    select tm.accno
         , a.accOpBal
         , sum(tm.transdebit) as mtd_d
         , sum(tm.transcredit) as mtd_c
         , 0 as ytd_d
         , 0 as ytd_c
    from accounts a
    right outer join transactions tm on tm.accno = a.accno
    where tm.transdt between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31'
    group by a.accno, a.accopbal
    union 
    select ty.accno
         , a.accOpBal
         , 0
         , 0
         , sum(ty.transdebit)
         , sum(ty.transcredit)
    from accounts a
    right outer join transactions ty on ty.accno = a.accno
    and ty.transdt between '2013-07-01' and  '2014-01-31'
    group by a.accno, a.accopbal
) alltxn
group by accno, accopbal
```

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48c951/2) with a small test set

and here is the testset:

```
-- january
insert into transactions values (1, 'alfki', '2014-01-01', 1,3); 
insert into transactions values (1, 'alfki', '2014-01-02', 1,3); 
insert into transactions values (1, 'alfki', '2014-01-03', 1,3); 

-- last year
insert into transactions values (1, 'alfki', '2013-09-01', 5,2);

-- txn without acc
insert into transactions values (1, 'noexi', '2014-01-03', 4,2); 


-- acc with txn
INSERT INTO Accounts values ( 'alfki', 'alfred', 4);
-- acc without txn
INSERT INTO Accounts values ( 'lefto', 'lefto', 6);
```

with the following query result:

```
ACCNO | ACCOPBAL |SUM(MTD_D)|SUM(MTD_C)|SUM(YTD_D)|SUM(YTD_C)
------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------
alfki |  4       |      3   |     9    |    8     |   11
lefto |  6       |      0   |     0    |    0     |    0
noexi | (null)   |      4   |     2    |    4     |    2
```

Comment: Actually that is not necessary that every Account has a record in both tables, and unfortunately outer join is not supported in MySql

Comment: above sql works if there is records in both tables, requirement is to generate query while the record is available one or both tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fix...SQL query works very well..however if there are no transactions for Accounts and only AccOpBal, the query is not return that AccNo..is there another UNION or JOIN required???

Comment: So sorry...I got it...that was a silly mistake at my end...now it works perfectly...

Comment: @rene can you explain why you used `where tn.accno is null`

Comment: @SyedArifIqbal Because that selects the records from account that don't have a record in  transaction  (notice the outer join).